# Message format in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am viewing my logstash output and it has:

> u0002\u0000\u0000xp\u0000\u0000\u0000\

characters.

I want to be able to view only understandable charsets. What changes should I have in my config file?

Comment: also, it complains to have received unexpected charset...

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the codecs, e.g. the [JSON codec](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/codecs/json). Here you can set a charset depending on the encoding of your input.

Example usage (for ISO-8859-1 charset):

```
input {
    file {
        path => [ "/path/to/logs" ]
        codec => json { charset => "ISO-8859-1" }
    }
}
```